# Why tuples in a set won't convert to any other type in a loop?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to remove a certain item from a set of tuples. to do so I must convert the tuples to a list or a set (i.e. a mutable object). I'm trying to do in a for loop but the tuples won't convert and my item is yet to be removed.

```
a = [('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
for i in a:
    i = list(i)
    if 'C' in i:
       i.remove('C')
print(a)
```

This is the output:
[('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]

Comment: You're successfully modifying the list you create, but do not save it anywhere

Comment: You create a new list with `i = list(i)`; you no longer have a reference to the (immutable anyway) tuple in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You got the right intuition. As your tuples are immutable, you need to create new ones.

However, in your code, you create lists, modify them, but fail to save them back in the original list.

You could use a list comprehension.

```
[tuple(e for e in t if e != 'C') for t in a]
```

Output:

```
[('A',), ('B',), ('B',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the list but are not creating a new list.
Try this:

```
a = [('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
b = []
for i in a:
    i = list(i)
    if 'C' in i:
       i.remove('C')
    b.append(i)
print(b)
```